# Laravel / Postgre SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired (SQL: select * from "document")

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, api, timeout

In my local laravel environment I don't have any problems connecting.

But in production I'm getting this:

```
return "SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired (SQL: select * from "document")" in all routes that queries the bank..
```

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=**.**.**.**
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=***********
DB_USERNAME=************
DB_PASSWORD=***************
```

Comment: SQLSTATE 08006 is connection failure.

Comment: the problem is that using the same bank the local api works.

Comment: have you double checked the credentials?

Comment: it was probably cache, again a wrong password then put the correct one and cleared the cache it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in the cache, noticed the password change for an incorrect one and I clicked the new one again and gave p

```
php artisan config:cache
```

started working again